# Why is LGBM 's prediction function returning a value error?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I'm trying to setup a model for cross validation, but I can't seem to figure out why the prediction function isn't working.
Here is my code:

```
results = {}

kf = KFold(3, shuffle=True) 
c=0
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X, y):
    c+=1;print(c)
    mdl =  lgb.LGBMClassifier(objective="binary",  n_estimators=50, importance_type="gain")
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    mdl.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train, eval_metric=roc_auc_score, )
    #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    y_proba = mdl.predict_proba(X_test, y_test)
    results["estimator"] =mdl
    results["score"] = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_proba[:, 1])
    results["feature_importances"] = [mdl.feature_names, mdl.feature_importances_]
```

And here is the error stack:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-d5ef259cd27f> in <module>
     10     mdl.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train, eval_metric=roc_auc_score, )
     11     #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
---> 12     y_proba = mdl.predict_proba(X_test, y_test)
     13     results["estimator"] =mdl
     14     results["score"] = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_proba[:, 1])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\sklearn.py in predict_proba(self, X, raw_score, start_iteration, num_iteration, pred_leaf, pred_contrib, **kwargs)
    918                       pred_leaf=False, pred_contrib=False, **kwargs):
    919         """Docstring is set after definition, using a template."""
--> 920         result = super().predict(X, raw_score, start_iteration, num_iteration, pred_leaf, pred_contrib, **kwargs)
    921         if callable(self._objective) and not (raw_score or pred_leaf or pred_contrib):
    922             _log_warning("Cannot compute class probabilities or labels "

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\sklearn.py in predict(self, X, raw_score, start_iteration, num_iteration, pred_leaf, pred_contrib, **kwargs)
    724                              "input n_features is %s "
    725                              % (self._n_features, n_features))
--> 726         return self._Booster.predict(X, raw_score=raw_score, start_iteration=start_iteration, num_iteration=num_iteration,
    727                                      pred_leaf=pred_leaf, pred_contrib=pred_contrib, **kwargs)
    728 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py in predict(self, data, start_iteration, num_iteration, raw_score, pred_leaf, pred_contrib, data_has_header, is_reshape, **kwargs)
   3140             else:
   3141                 num_iteration = -1
-> 3142         return predictor.predict(data, start_iteration, num_iteration,
   3143                                  raw_score, pred_leaf, pred_contrib,
   3144                                  data_has_header, is_reshape)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py in predict(self, data, start_iteration, num_iteration, raw_score, pred_leaf, pred_contrib, data_has_header, is_reshape)
    698         data = _data_from_pandas(data, None, None, self.pandas_categorical)[0]
    699         predict_type = C_API_PREDICT_NORMAL
--> 700         if raw_score:
    701             predict_type = C_API_PREDICT_RAW_SCORE
    702         if pred_leaf:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1440     @final
   1441     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1442         raise ValueError(
   1443             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1444             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I can't think of a reason why it would be trying to test the truthiness of an array in this instance.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the shape/content of `X_test` and `y_test`?

Comment: Check the inputs to the problem function call, `mdl.predict_proba(X_test, y_test)`.  I haven't used this code, but it looks like it expects the 2nd argument to be a scalar, a single value (`raw_score`).  Instead you have given it an array.  Check, and recheck, that your arguments match the documentation.

Comment: thanks. it seems obvious now. I must have gotten tunnel vision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs

https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html

the 2nd argument is `raw_score` boolean - a single True/False value.  You pass `y_test`.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was going to be something dumb.